# How to determine the types of the whitespaces when reading from a file in java?

Tags: java, split, io, escaping, whitespace

I want to read a file's contents and split every time that I reach to a whitespace and do "action 1" on the splitted string if there was an "space" before it, "action 2" if there was a "tab" before it and "action 3" if there was a "newline" before it.

Actions are not important. My question is how can i read the file such that i can determine the type of the whitespace i read?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "whitespace"?

Comment: @CardinalSystem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: For example i couldn't do it by using DataInputStream and BufferedInputStream. Maybe I'm not familiar enough with these classes' functions.

Comment: Use a `Scanner` and `String#split(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `str.split("/n")` for newline, `str.split("/t")` for tabs and  `str.split(" ")` for spaces. For example `String [] result = "before tab [ TAB ] after tab".split("/t")` if `result.length >= 2` than you found tab character, so you know that there is tab character after `result[0]` or before `result[1]`( same with space, new line e.g)

Comment: How does it answer the question "how  can I determine the type of the whitespace"?

Comment: `String [] stringWithTab = "before tab [ TAB ] after tab".split("/t")` if `stringWithTab.length >= 2` `than you found tab character, same with space, new line e.g.

Comment: Sorry c0der, I was working on 4 projects at the same time and i had a very near deadline so I didn't get any time to update the answer. Thanks to everyone. Nikolai's answer helped me a lot.